# LEFT-POINTING MAGNIFYING GLASS and chrome

Tags: google-chrome, unicode

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=magnifying&preview=entity

<- this shows up in ie9 ie10 and firefox, but not in chrome

Why? How can I fix this? I would like to use in the `<title>` of a webpage

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Font support to the character LEFT-POINTING MAGNIFYING GLASS U+1F50D is very limited, probably just Quivira, Segoe UI Symbol, and Symbola. Of these, Segoe UI Symbol is shipped with some modern versions of Windows, whereas the other too are free fonts that users can download and install, but most people don’t do such things. Thus, you should not expect such a character to be displayed properly even in normal content, still less in special contexts like `title` elements.

The `title` element is not rendered as normal content, only in a browser-specific manner outside the page, e.g. in an address bar or tab bar. Such rendering is browser-dependent, immune to anything you say in CSS, and uses some font chosen by the browser. Apparently, in some modern versions of some browsers in some modern versions of Windows, the font used is Segoe UI Symbol. In other situations, it is some font that lacks this character.

Thus, there is no fix. The `title` element value should be written so that it serves its different purposes (including its importance to search engines), rather than tuned to suit a particular use.

Comment: I just feel like I could use it responsibly, if it wasn't for chrome. I tested it in multiple vinnilla setups on different browsers and os's. only chrome fails.

Comment: @Fresheyeball, it’s a much broader problem – Segoe UI Symbol is rather new, and really available in new versions of Windows only (I don’t think even Vista has it).

Comment: I am targeting window 7+ and osx only.